# touch tmp/restart.txt not working

Tags: apache, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm hosting a rails 4.2 app on digital ocean, with the 1 click installer.

At the beginning everything was working fine and I was able to restart by touching `tmp/restart.txt`, but now is not working, to restart my app I have to do `service unicorn restart`.

Where is the configuration for this or how can I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

You restart unicorn by sending `USR2` to it, touching `tmp/restart.txt` is a passenger-specific thing, so either you were running your app under passenger when it was working - or possibly (seems very unlikely to me) Digital Ocean had some watcher looking at that file and triggering the proper unicorn restart whenever that file changed.

Either way, your best bet here is to contact DO support for any questions you have.